# I have two title in my database and I take a while loop, I want to display multi collapse title how much that I have title records in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

And this is the code.

```
 <body>
    <br>
    <div class="card">
    <?php
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo '<div class="card-header">';
            echo '<h5 class="mb-0">';
            echo '<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  
            aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">';

            echo $row['title'];

           echo '</button>';
           echo '</h5>';
           echo '</div>';
           echo '</div>';
       }
   ?>
  </div>
</body>
```

but now it display the second record with one collapse title, it must dispaly two title with two collapse title.

Comment: You have one too many closing div tags </div> after your closing h5 tag. This could be throwing things off

Comment: Even I removed those tags but no result

Comment: I think you main card div <div class='card'>...</div> is meant to be included in your while loop too.

Answer (score 0):

Place the main card div within your while loop:

```
<body>
<br>
<?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo '<div class="card">';
        echo '<div class="card-header">';
        echo '<h5 class="mb-0">';
        echo '<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"  
        aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">';

        echo $row['title'];

       echo '</button>';
       echo '</h5>';
       echo '</div>';
       echo '</div>';
   }
?>
</body>
```

Comment: No result, even I include card class also.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what's going wrong because I can't test with your $result table. I tried your code out using a for loop, and it created a card for each iteration of the loop no problem, so I'm inclined to think that the problem might then be with the data.
To test, try commenting out all the echos in your while loop and only echo out the $row['title']; and check that each title you expect is shown in the output.

Comment: No, again it's not working even I deleted echo from div just I echo $row, it gives error

Comment: If you're not able to echo the title out, the problem seems to be that your table does not contain the info as you expect it to. When you say you're getting an error, are you getting an actual PHP error, or is it just not display the titles as you want?